# Using `fillRect` to paint onto a 3D model is too slow?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I am currently trying to implement a painting type app in three.js/canvas.

I want to be able to paint onto a 3D model which will in turn update the UV map.

[image: Progress so far]

I've tried a few different methods, in my current version I am pretty happy with the functionality but the performance is bad.

In this version I am recording the 2D canvas strokes and once the mouse has stopped drawing (mouseup) then I iterate over the canvas to project each pixel at the model and find the UV coordinates equivalent and use fillrect to draw that specific pixel in the correct position on the UV map.

This does work but there must be a more efficient way of doing it, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
for (var iy = 0; iy < height; iy++){
    for (var ix = 0; ix < width; ix++){

    var red = imgData.data[((width * iy) + ix) * 4];
    var green = imgData.data[(((width * iy) + ix) * 4) + 1];
    var blue = imgData.data[(((width * iy) + ix) * 4) + 2];
    var alpha = imgData.data[(((width * iy) + ix) * 4) + 3];

    array = getMousePosition( container, ix+300, iy+300);
    onClickPosition.fromArray( array );

    intersects = getIntersects( onClickPosition, arrayMesh );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ){
        var uv = intersects[ 0 ].uv;
        intersects[ 0 ].object.material.map.transformUv( uv );
        currentPoint = { x: Math.round(uv.x*canvas.width), y: Math.round(uv.y*canvas.height) };
        ctx.fillRect(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y, 1, 1);
    }

    }
 }
```

Comment: This question seems legitimate (using `fillRect` to project onto a UV map is too slow), but the title is misleading and might get the question closed. I made a small change, but if you can improve it more (or want to revert my edit), please do. "Best way" questions tend to be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: @ssube OK, I'll keep that in mind. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the texture you're writing to is a canvas (since you "use fillrect to draw that specific pixel in the correct position on the UV map").

Rather than using `fillrect` hundreds or thousands of times, I would try getting at the [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) directly and just setting the pixels yourself. It is *much* faster on single-pixel writes, since no function calls happen during the update.

If you want to get clever, you can let the mouse write to one canvas (typically in grayscale) then project that scratch canvas onto your model and UV map, then simply use it as a filter for additive blending of the paint color (and/or texture). That's a nice easy way to paint an image onto a model (i.e., you paint the mask, then multiply the image by that before adding).

Comment: I did try using ImageData before, but from my tests `fillRect` gave me a smoother result and I didn't see any difference in performance.

I'll look into using a canvas as a filter though, thanks.

Comment: @NiallMcKenna That doesn't seem right. Writing to the image data should be *much* faster than `fillRect`, even if `fillRect` isn't your main bottleneck. Can you include your code and any benchmarking info you have in the question?

Comment: I've updated the question with some code, its a bit rough but it should show the idea. I just had a quick look over which part is causing the bottleneck, and it looks like its the `getIntersects()` method.

Comment: @NiallMcKenna that makes sense, picking is complex math and you're calling it every pixel. Can you add a test to check if the pixel is empty (probably black and transparent) before picking, so you don't have to map empty pixels?

Comment: I've added in a check so its not picking the transparent pixels, it performs slightly faster but its still a little sluggish.

Comment: @NiallMcKenna You should consider accepting answers to some of your questions if you found them helpful.  Thanks.